# Does Azure KeyVault .net SDK i.e. KeyVaultClient perform if there are transient errors eg. transient network failure

Tags: azure-keyvault

Does KeyVaultClient (.net and python sdk) perform retries internally if there are transient errors? Like a transient network failure?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the KeyVaultClient doesn't by default.

Here's a good discussion on similar topic and some ideas on how to retry using ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy -
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b1efee08-e4a7-47fc-a1ea-13ade0faad96/handling-transient-error-handling-in-keyvault?forum=AzureKeyVault

You can also look at the source code.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/KeyVault/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault/KeyVaultClient.cs